# Use of Indefinite Article, Plural Noun and Subject Verb Agreement

Tags: verbs, nouns, subject-verb-agreement, indefinite-article, plural-forms

There has been written in my text book:

> *Penicillin was not used in the treatment of disease until **a means** was found of concentrating it.*

I am astonished with the fact that why the writer used **A** before a plural word (**means**) and why not he used **were** after means instead of **was**, in order to satisfy subject verb agreement?

Comment: Please consult an English language dictionary to learn the meaning of the noun _means,_ which is a singular, countable noun meaning _"a method, instrument or process used to accomplish something"_. Your astonishment will end.

Comment: "Means" is a count noun with identical singular and plural forms. There is no form "mean" for the sense we're discussing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Means" here is not plural. It is a singular that happens to end with an "s". The plural form is the same as the singular form. "We have found only one means to accomplish this goal." "We found two means to accomplish this goal."

For definition, see http://www.thefreedictionary.com/means, scroll down to the fourth main heading, "means". (After three definitions for "mean", without an "s".)

There are a few singular nouns that end with "s", like "nucleus", "princess", and "bus".